# 'take' action right after caching RDD causes only 2% caching

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD which is formed by reading a local text file of size of roughly 117MB.

```
scala> rdd
res87: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[3] at textFile at <console>:24
```

I cache the RDD:-

```
scala> rdd.persist()
res84: rdd.type = MapPartitionsRDD[3] at textFile at <console>:24
```

After this I call the '**take(1)**' action on the RDD to force evalulation. Once this is done, I check the Spark UI's Storage page. It shows me fraction cached is 2% only, size in memory being 6.5MB. Then I call '**count**' action on the RDD. After this when I check the Spark UI Storage page I suddenly see that those numbers have now changed. The fraction cached is 82% and size in memory is 258.2MB. Does it mean that even after caching an RDD, Spark only really caches what is really required for the subsequent action (since **take(1)** only reads one top element)? And when the second action '**count**' was triggered,  it needed to touch all the elements, so it ended up caching the remaining part as well? I have not come across any documented behavior like this, is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the source code, you are right. RDD reference is only saved to HashMap of persisted RDDs and is registered with special cleaner when persist() is called. So caching is performed during real reading of the data. More over it's can be displaced (for example when not enough memory and active reference to data doesn't exist).

Comment: I am still confused. I understand that the caching is performed when action is triggered, but then 'take' is also an action, even though take(1) is reading only the first element, but still technically an action. The documentation doesn't refer to such a thing called partial caching which is happening here. As long as any action is triggered, caching takes place. Also, if we are to say that it is caching whatever it's reading, that also doesn't sound right, because the first element is just a line of text (much lesser than 1KB). It doesn't need 6.5MB just to store that.

Comment: 1 line is that you want but hdfs stores data in large blocks (measured in MB). When you ask one line, entire block is read anyway. When you ask two lines, 1 or 2 blocks would be read (lines location may be in same block or in different).

Comment: But this example I have tried on my local system mode within Scala shell. So the file system used was the local file system.

Comment: Afaic, spark local environment includes hadoop. More precise answer also could be find in source code but is maybe long story (with dependence on certain environment). I think high precision of magnitude is not important for practical cases.

Answer (score 1):

Spark only materializes rdds on demand, that is in response to an action as mentioned in the previous answer. Most actions require to read all partitions of the rdd such us `count()` but other actions do not require to materialize all partitions and for performance reasons they don't. `take(x)` and `first()`, which is essentially `take(1)`, are examples of such actions. Imagine a case where you have an rdd with millions of records and many partitions and you only need to examine a few records through `take(x)`. Materializing the entire rdd would be wasteful. Instead Spark materializes a single partition and examines the number of items it contains. Based on that number it materializes more partitions to cover the needs of `take(x)` (I am simplifying the logic of `take(x)` here).

In your case `take(1)` requires a single partition so only 1 partition is materialized and cached. Then when you do a `count()` all partitions need to be materialized and cached to the extend your available memory allows.